# Where is my Angularjs minify error? Error $injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify, angularjs-injector

I'm running into that annoying Angular minify problem (I really hope this issue is non-existent in Angular 2)

I've commented out all my app module injections and going down the list 1 by 1 to find out where the problem is and I think I narrowed it down to my **searchPopoverDirectives**:

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Original code, produces [**this error**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=eProvider%20%3C-%20e) `Unknown provider: eProvider <- e`:

```
(function() { "use strict";

    var app = angular.module('searchPopoverDirectives', [])

    .directive('searchPopover', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl : "popovers/searchPopover/searchPopover.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            scope       : false,
            controller  : function($scope) {

                // Init SearchPopover scope:
                // -------------------------
                var vs = $scope;
                vs.searchPopoverDisplay = false;

            }
        }
    })

})();
```

I then tried the `[]` syntax in an attempt to fix the minify problem and ran into [**this error**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$scopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20searchPopoverDirective) `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- searchPopoverDirective`:

```
(function() { "use strict";

    var app = angular.module('searchPopoverDirectives', [])

    .directive('searchPopover', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        return {
            templateUrl : "popovers/searchPopover/searchPopover.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            scope       : false,
            controller  : function($scope) {

                // Init SearchPopover scope:
                // -------------------------
                var vs = $scope;
                vs.searchPopoverDisplay = false;

            }
        }
    }])

})();
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Also found out this guy is causing a problem:

```
.directive('focusMe', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.focusMe);
            scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
                if (value === true) { 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        element[0].focus(); 
                    });
                }
            });
            element.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: you tried [] syntax in wrong place :-) move it from directive ( where you not dependency), to controller function

Comment: _on update_: here you solution with directives should work :-)

Comment: I use ng-annotate (https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) before minifying. It does that automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you minify code, it minify all code, so your

```
controller  : function($scope) {
```

was minified to something like

```
controller  : function(e) {
```

so, just use

```
controller  : ["$scope", function($scope) { ... }]
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Yeah.. this bug really drives me nuts! I need to remember to keep minify on as often as possible... just makes debugging hard :(

Comment: @LeonGaban you just need remember  [A note on minification](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification): _Use an inline annotation where, instead of just providing the function, you provide an array._

Answer (score 4):

When minifying javascript the parameter names are changed but strings remain the same.
You have 2 ways that you can define which services need to be injected:

1. Inline Annotation:

   ```
   phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
       ...
   }]);
   ```
2. Using the `$inject` property:

   ```
   phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', PhoneListCtrl);

   PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

   function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http){
       ...
   }
   ```

Using `$inject` is considered more readable than inline annotations. It is best practice to always have one line declaring the `controller`, `service`, or `directive`, one line for defining the injection values, and finally the implementation method. The method may be defined last due to the hoisting nature of javascript.

**Remember: The order of your annotation (strings) and your function parameters must be the same!**