# Find cause of AngularJS $injector:strictdi error messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting an error message in a fairly complex app, but Angular does not provide a filename or line number indicating where the error was thrown initially. I have gotten used to this with Angular and I've been able to find the cause of errors nonetheless in the past, but not this time. This is the error:

```
Error: [$injector:strictdi] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(%24compile)
    at angular.js:38
    at Function.eb.$$annotate (angular.js:4072)
    at e (angular.js:4799)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4834)
    at angular.js:7943
    at q (angular.js:357)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:7941)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)
    at Object.$get (angular.js:4676)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)
```

We're using $compile in a lot of different places in our app, including a number of third party directives/modules. My question is: is there any way to find the piece of code that's causing this error? I have been searching for '$compile' in my source code, but that gives me so many results that it doesn't really help.

Is there any way to enable better stack traces including my own source, not just AngularJS functions? If this does not exist, I'd like to know it too and I'll have to find another way to fix this, but I hope I'm not missing something here.

Comment: Do you only get this error after minifying your app JavaScript?

Comment: I can try to disable minification. Give me a minute to test this. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127409/where-is-my-angularjs-minify-error-error-injector

Comment: I disabled sourcemaps and minification/optimization, but with the JS code just concatenated and not processed/modified in any other way, I still get this error with the same stack trace.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi?p0=function($compile) ... function($compile) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode

Comment: I ran into this exact error when i minfied my app. Are you doing your dependency injections explicitly? [refrence](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope, dep1, dep2) {

Comment: Yes, but there could be some place in our code or some third party directive where it's still in non-explicit/strict mode. I know what causes this error, I just can't find _where_ it went wrong.

Comment: Maybe search for (', function) as this would be an implicit declaration and a function proceeded by a string is fairly uncommon? Of course you would have to look for other versions too ... (", function) and (",function) and (',function) ... single quote, double quote, and space

Comment: I will try that, thanks.

Comment: Change your task (or your way) for adding scripts and add the third party libraries one by one. In this way you can easily identify the third party library which creates issues. Moreover there are plugins which creates on the fly the right injection dependencies which could directly fix your issue because will fix the third party library which doesnt implement injections correctly